# How to implement LESS css with magento?

Tags: css, blocks, theme

I want to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) CSS processing for theme development. Normally to implement LESS processor all you need to do is to add following lines to `<head>` tag in your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In Magento I tried to add following line to my **local.xml** file with no luck

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.less</name></action>
```

This is so because LESS requires rel attribute to be `rel="stylesheet/less"` , but magento obviously adds just `rel="stylesheet"` with addItem method.
I also tried to overwrite rel tag with `<param>rel="stylesheet/less"</param>`, but again with no result. Is there any workaround ? or any other solutions out there?
BTW. I did also find this [this plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesscss-5369.html), but this also did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is what they call 'hack', but it solved my problem. After all it is only for development. I will compile normal css file later and remove less.js.
So the **solution is:**
Add following lines to your **local.xml** file:

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action><!-- remove main stylesheet -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.less</name><params>id="less"</params></action><!-- add you less file with id="less" -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/less.js</name></action><!-- include less compiler -->
```

and the 'hack' part is to open your **less.js** file and search for `rel==="stylesheet/less"` and change it to `id==="less"`
**This solution is meant only for development.** If you're done with less, compile it to css and remove those 3 lines from your local.xml
 or if you are and you should, developing in localhost, you can just keep those 3 lines in your localhost and not in server install ;) This way all you have to do after finishing edit, is open cmd, compile css and upload it to server. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Erfan's solution is good enough. But as ruuter said, you need to keep a correct order when include less files. In that case you can add both css and js files via setText method() :

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="core/text" name="lesscss">
    <action method="setText">
        <less>
            <![CDATA[
                <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="path/to/skin/custom.less" media="all" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/skin/js/less.js"></script>
            ]]>
        </less>
    </action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Agree, it's not the best solution. However, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

A less savvy solution would be to place the script tag into the **"Miscellaneous Scripts"** area of **System > Config > Design**. This allows editing via CMS and you can configure it to be managed at differing store views. Not terribly elegant, but allows you the flexibility to add/remove in a dev environment at-will.

[image: Less CSS in Misc Scripts]

Comment: That's Nice solution, but you still have to remove default stylesheet in local.xml, so I think doing it all in there is quicker ;) Once you've edited your less.js for magento once, you can always use the same one. No need to do this every new project. So adding 3 lines to local.xml is quicker than using admin and local.xml anyway :) 
Also I have to point out that less.js has to be inserted after stylesheet, not before ;)
Tnx for the answer anyway, it expanded my perspective to magento once more :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hacking LESS, another option is to add something like the following to your local.xml:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="lesscss">
        <action method="setText">
            <css><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="path/to/skin/custom.less" media="all" />]]></css>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

IMO, the best solution is to create a module that extends the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head class` and adds a addLess method or something, and also adds configuration in the backend: "enable live mode". Hmm, the [module you linked](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesscss-5369.html) looks interesting actually, if you have time you should look into why it's not working for you...

Comment: This is not working, because it adds this <link> to the end of <head> tag, after including less.js, but it has to be included before. Any tricks how to add <script> tag after it ?
About the plugin. Yes, looks interesting, but did not work. I sent email to them, no answer yet and no time to wait. Right now my solution seems still quickest =)

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful using less.js in a production environment. Each request to a page will require a new compilation of the less.css file. A more sustainable route is to look at your deployment, When you push a change live / development have the deployment compile the less into css.

That way you can minimize css, cache and help reduce load time.

Comment: I think a mentioned this many times in my answer. Using LESS is only for development. Always compile css for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

To include less.css with `rel='stylesheet/less"` file in local.xml, `addLinkRel()` method of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` can be used,

```
<action method="addLinkRel">
   <rel>stylesheet/less</rel>
   <href>path/to/less/file</href>
</action>
```

In my case, I included bootstrap.less in header, and less.js using `setText()` so that the JS always includes after the less file. And it seems to work. My complete xml for the head is:

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addLinkRel">
    <rel>stylesheet/less</rel>
    <href>skin/frontend/magentodev/default/css/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less</href>
 </action>
 <block type="core/text" name="less.css">
   <action method="setText">
     <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/magentodev/default/js/less/less-1.5.0.min.js"/>]]></text>
   </action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

**Update:**

There was a problem using `addLinkRel()` method, because it needs a full url(I suppose) as arguement for `<href></href>` tags. So I finally ended up my `local.xml` look like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less</name><params>class="stylesheet-less"</params></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/magentodev.less</name><params>class="stylesheet-less"</params></action>
    <block type="core/text" name="stylesheet-less">
        <action method="setText">
           <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">jQuery('.stylesheet-less').attr('rel', 'stylesheet/less');</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
<reference name="after_body_start">
    <block type="core/template" name="global.js" template="/page/html/globalJs.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
</reference>
```

Content of `globalJs.phtml`:

```
<?php
/*
 * Base Theme
 */
?>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/less/less-1.5.0.min.js')?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And Yes, this setup should be used for development. Not for Production server.